# Report Viewer, impressão direta e salvamento de arquivo sem visualização

Tags: vb.net, relatório

Boa tarde.
Tem como salvar um relatório feito em REPORT VIEWER sem visualização prévia?
Salvando-o no formato PDF, e também realizando a sua impressão direta na impressora(sem ser por meio de executáveis externos), de maneira semelhante ao objeto PRINTER?

Answer (score 0):

É possível sim, através do próprio controle do Windows Form do ReportViewer.
Ao clicar no botão de imprimir na barra de ferramentas do form, será aberto a janela comum de impressão que é iniciado junto com as impressoras configuradas no computador do usuário.

Este [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251693.aspx) tem mais informações e pode ser útil.

Comment: Mas quero realizar a impressão e salvá-lo sem a visualização da janela do form.